# Generate Nested List (Tree) from Flat List

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have a plain class named MenuModel in Java (it's for nested menu as the name suggests) like this:

```
public class MenuModel {
    public String id;
    public String parentId = null;
    public String title;

    public MenuModel parent = null;
    public List<MenuModel> children = new ArrayList<MenuModel>(); 
 }
```

My code fetch data from web API and generate a flat list of MenuModel with only `id`, `parentId`, and `title` fields filled with data. However, **I need each MenuModel to have references to its parent and (optionally) children for further uses**.

I have thought of a method which make a nested loop to pair the models each other and check if they are parent and child. But I think that costs too much (n^2 or n^3 complexity, the itemset is large) and can only fill the `parent` field.

What is the best way to achieve this in Java? To summarize:

- Input: `ArrayList<MenuModel> source`
- Output: `ArrayList<MenuModel> result` containing all MenuModel from source which has `parentId = null` (that means, it's top level menu), with each MenuModel has children fields filled with reference to their respective children MenuModel. Additionally, each children have reference to their parents.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What establishes the parent child relationship? How do you intend to construct these?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's indicated by `parentId` attribute on each model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go through all the records and add them to a `HashMap<String, MenuModel>` (the key being the ID).

Then, for each record `record`:

- Look up the parent ID in the above map to get `parent`.
- Assign the parent to this record's parent variable - `record.parent = parent`.
- Add this record to the parent's list of children - `parent.children.add(record)`.

**Running time:** Expected O(n).